# Is volume of the function $f(x,y)=1$ over the region $D$, gives the area of the region...

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What I know while calculating $\iint_D f(x,y) dxdy $ is basically we are calculating the volume  under the function $f(x,y)$ over the region D..

But when I was asked to calculate area of $x^2+y^2=25$ using the double integral, I was told to take $f(x,y)=1,i.e.I=\int_{-5}^5\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx$..This I am not getting...This will mean the volume under the function $f(x,y)=1$ over the region $x^2+y^2=25$ is same as the area of the region $x^2+y^2=25$....but how..?

I am not getting a explanation for this...Someone please explain me this..

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: is 1 the height of the volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for simplicity $f\geqslant0$ and having $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ we can write
$$\iint\limits_D f(x,y) dxdy=\iint\limits_D\int\limits_{0}^{f(x,y)}dxdydz\quad(1)$$
and understand it as volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

When $f=1$, then we have a curved cylinder with a height of 1 and its volume numerically coincides with the area of the base $D$.

$(1)$ can also be understood as the mass of a flat plate $D$ with density $f$.

In same way if $D\subset \mathbb{R}$,
$$\int\limits_D f(x) dx=\int\limits_D\int\limits_{0}^{f(x)}dxdy\quad(2)$$
and we can understand it as area of a curvilinear flat figure. If here we take $f=1$, then we find, that area $(2)$ equals numerically to $D$'s measure. Aslo, $(2)$ can also be understood as the mass of a linear set $D$ with density $f$.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually do in your first example is $$\iint_D\int_0^{f(x,y)}1\;\mathrm{d}z\;\mathrm{d}x\;\mathrm{d}y = \iint_Df(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}x\;\mathrm{d}y.$$

As you can see this is a bit besides the point but you use the function $1$ as well here in some sense, since you actually set the boundaries in $3$ dimensions and use $1$ as the integrandum.

The big explanation for your second paragraph is that when you calculate what $D$ is, you get that it's just the circle $x^2+y^2=25$. So when you try to find the volume with $f(x,y)=1$, then you are just calculating the volume of the cylinder with height $1$ and with a base with surface area $25\pi$ (that's the surface area that they are actually asking you to calculate), meaning the volume of the cylinder will be equal to the surface area of its base.